# Undo functionality in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to implement undo functionality in `JTextArea`. Googled for tutorial and followed one of the tutorial and wrote the below code. The event is triggered when Ctrl+Z key is pressed. Its not working for me. Am I missing something?

```
private void undoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Document doc = editorTextArea.getDocument();
    final UndoManager undo = new UndoManager();

    doc.addUndoableEditListener(new UndoableEditListener() {
        @Override
        public void undoableEditHappened(UndoableEditEvent e) {
            undo.addEdit(e.getEdit());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Not sure what tutorial you read but code from [this tutorial](http://www.javareference.com/jrexamples/viewexample.jsp?id=16) works fine for me

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From you're example, it's difficult to know how much you've done, but I was able to get this to work...

```
private UndoManager undoManager;

// In the constructor

undoManager = new UndoManager();
Document doc = textArea.getDocument();
doc.addUndoableEditListener(new UndoableEditListener() {
    @Override
    public void undoableEditHappened(UndoableEditEvent e) {

        System.out.println("Add edit");
        undoManager.addEdit(e.getEdit());

    }
});

InputMap im = textArea.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
ActionMap am = textArea.getActionMap();

im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask()), "Undo");
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Y, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask()), "Redo");

am.put("Undo", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            if (undoManager.canUndo()) {
                undoManager.undo();
            }
        } catch (CannotUndoException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
am.put("Redo", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            if (undoManager.canRedo()) {
                undoManager.redo();
            }
        } catch (CannotUndoException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: 1+ Key Bindings are the way to go here.

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+Z is also common as Redo shortcut, I suggest adding: `im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask() | Event.SHIFT_MASK), "Redo");`

Comment: Also creating the `UndoableEditListener` isn't necessary, this can be replaced with `doc.addUndoableEditListener(undoManager);`

Comment: @EmmanuelBourg The purpose of using the listener was to demonstrate that it worked

Comment: @EmmanuelBourg I think I took redo either from netbeans or word, can't remember :P

Comment: 'getMenuShortcutKeyMask()' is deprecated, please update the answer with more modern approach

Comment: @jazor [`Toolkit.html#getMenuShortcutKeyMaskEx`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getMenuShortcutKeyMaskEx())

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but maybe you can not addKeyListener for your gui.

For example;

```
class Example implements KeyListener{

  .
  .
  .

  this.addKeyListener(this); // if want to add key listener for main container

  .
  .
  .

}
```

[this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) is about how to use key listener.

Comment: keylisteners are added.  I am using netbeans.  undo is a menu item

Comment: No, don't use a KeyListener as that's too low level. Swing components use key bindings as recommended by MadProgrammer.